# Cannot add border to the button

Tags: css

I want to add the border to my button in the webpage, following is what I do.

The strange things it that the color set works, which can control the font color within the button, but the sets for the border does not work.

I have tried some solutions with highest votes, but none of them works.

```
.btn-general {
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 12px 26px 12px 26px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: "_…does not work…_" is usually a very [low-quality error description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you add the HTML code of the button, and explain exactly what 'does not work'? No border, no change in border?

Comment: Please add html as well.

Comment: add !important to code:border:2px solid #fff !important;

Answer (score -1):

I tried you code, and it seems to be working fine. Are you using bootstrap or something like that? Because if you are, it can be that Bootstrap is overwriting your CSS. You can try putting !important behind your css lines to see if it works.

```
<style>
.btn-general {
    color: #fff !important;
    border-color: #fff !important;
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-width: 2px !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    padding: 12px 26px 12px 26px !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}

</style>
<button class="btn-general">
Test
</button>
```

[image: Result of your code]

Comment: Use a more specific selector than the `!important`. More info on CSS Specificity: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/